# Ruby on Rails search form parameter initialisation at server startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Inspired by the tutorial from Michael Hartl, I developped a business rules assessment application.
When my user logs in, he lands on the home page, defined in routes.rb as

```
 root to: "dashboards#home"
```

The home page actually displays a dashboard of top 10 failling business rules, and 10 most recently updated ones. It's a start ... and it works fine.

Then I added a simple search as per RailsCast #37, to help filtering quickly some particular business rule. During the development, all worked correctly, but when I restart the rails server, I get this error message about the 'search' parameter:

```
undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
```

when assessing the 'search' parameter, it just does not exist yet !

Here is the code:

1. The home page is defined in the dashboards folder, and pushed by the
   dashboards controller.
2. The dashboard controller instanciates the @business_rules_search relying on the search function
3. the search function is implemented in the model.

The home page extract:

```
      <div class="span4">
      <h4>Search for Business Rules</h4>
      <%= form_tag :root, :method => 'get' do %>
        <p>
          <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
          <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
        </p>
      <% end %>
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Code</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Status</th>
        </tr>

      <% @business_rules_search.each do |business_rule| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= image_tag(index_audit_tag_for(business_rule), :alt => "Quality hit") %></td>
          <td class="col_narrow"><%= link_to business_rule.code, business_rule %></td>
          <td><%= business_rule.name %></td>
          <td><%= business_rule.status.name %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
      </table>

      </div>
```

The dashboard controller:

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController

  def home
    @business_rules_index=BusinessRule.pgnd(current_playground).order("score ASC").limit(10)
    @business_rules_updated=BusinessRule.pgnd(current_playground).order("updated_at DESC").limit(10)
    @business_rules_search=BusinessRule.pgnd(current_playground).search(params[:search]).limit(10)
  end

end
```

The search function:

```
def self.search(search)
  if not search.empty?
    where('name like ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    where('1=1')
  end
end
```

I hope you can help me understand why this parameter usage does not work after server restart ?

Thanks for your help,

Best regards,

Fred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.present?`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/present%3F) method:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search.present?
    where('name like ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    where('TRUE')
  end
end
```

`.present?` is very useful, it combines `.nil?` and `.empty?`:

```
nil.present? # => false
"".present? # => false
[].present? # => false
"hey".present? # => true
[1].presence? # => true
```

---

`.present?` is the exact opposite of `.blank?`:

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb, line 18
def present?
  !blank?
end

# File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb, line 13
def blank?
  respond_to?(:empty?) ? empty? : !self
end
```

So:

```
nil.blank? # => true
"".blank? # => true
[].blank? # => true
"hey".blank? # => false
[1].blank? # => false
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `present?` instead of `empty?`

```
def self.search(search)
  if search.present?
    where('name like ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    where('1=1')
  end
end
```

As `empty?` method is not defined for `NilClass`, you would definitely get an error `undefined method 'empty?' for nil:NilClass` when `search` parameter is `nil`. `empty?` method can be used on strings, arrays and hashes but not on `nil` object.

When `search` is `nil`, `search.present?` returns `false` so else condition would be executed.

When you restart the server and visit the root page of your application, `params[:search]` is  `nil` as you have not searched for anything and directly rendered the root page. When you actually *Search for Business Rules* by inputting a search string in the text field at that time `params[:search]` would not be `nil`.